# Locally connected metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

I have the following definition of a locally connected metric space. Given $(X,d)$ a metric space, $x \in X$ and given $U \ni x$ a neighbourhood. Then there exist a connected neighbourhood $V$ susch that $x\in V \subseteq U$.

However, in metric spaces, if $U$ is an neighbourhood for $x$, then $x \in \operatorname{int}(U)$ and then there exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq U$. But $B(x,\epsilon)$ is a connected neighbourhood of $x$ contained in $U$. Wouldn't this imply that it is therefore locally connected? I don't understand how can a metric space be therefore not locally connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is in thinking that $B(x,\epsilon)$ is necessarily connected. Consider the space $\Bbb Q$ of rationals with the usual metric: then $B(x,\epsilon)$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ for each $x\in\Bbb Q$ and $\epsilon>0$, so **no** $B(x,\epsilon)$ is connected.

Answer (score 1):

Why should $B(x,\varepsilon)$ always be connected? Not every space is as nice as the reals. For example, the set $\{0,1,1/2,1/3,...\}$ has bad connectivity around 0.